# Enabling anonymous submission of tickets via email in Request Tracker 4.4.1

Tags: email, rt

Like the title states, I want to enable the anonymous submission of tickets via email in Request Tracker 4.4.1. And by anonymous, I mean not need to be a User in RT, just send an email from any address to a Queue in RT (helpdesk@example.com) to create a ticket.

Currently, I have configured the **Queue** such that under **Group Rights**, **SYSTEM >> Everyone**, and **ROLES >> Requester** have the ability to **Create Ticket**. This is what Best Practical's RT documentation stated to do, but tickets still cannot be created from any email address.

Best Pracical RT Docs: https://docs.bestpractical.com/rt/4.4.1/index.html

Comment: UPDATE: Also changed config variable **$ValidateEmailAddresses** from **1** to **0**, still no luck

Comment: UPDATE: Noticed the following bounce email in my Gmail Spam folder after trying to submit through there: You do not have permission to communicate with RT

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand this question, so I assume there can be two approaches.

1. All tickets are raised anonymously by users.
2. Mostly tickets are raised with username, but sometimes the user can opt to post request anonymously.

For both the above cases, create Anonymous user first and assign requisite rights.
For first use case, a scrip would be required to change the requestor from any email address to the Anonymous user, whenever a ticket is created. This allows you keep an account of who actually requested the ticket for history reasons.

For second, ask your users to mention "Anonymous" or some string,when they wish to raise a ticket anonymously. On reading the string on the first line, a scrip can make the anonymous user as the requestor of the ticket.